# Force loading, before use, Image Source in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I making simple game in the WinRT (C# + XAML) with animations.

I have every key frame as a png file. I create animation from `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` class witch changes Source property of Image control. It's work, but at 1st time of each animation can be seen 'blink' effect when application load BitmapImages for specific animation.

It is possible to load each of BitmapImage before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One way to be would to load it manually via a Stream like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/eaf702e8-94fd-45b6-937c-0f36c5ce2683/can-i-some-how-preload-images-before-page-load?forum=winappswithcsharp). You could have references to the different `BitmapImage` objects in your `ViewModel`.

The second option would be to manually precache all the images beforehand. Draw them on the screen in the background once. You may even be able to do this with Opactiy at 0 so that there's no chance of them being seen.